# Variable doesn't update in the View

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to disable all the `button`'s, when `selectedplace` is `null`, this works, when the Dialog first starts, but when I change the option it is activated all the time.

This shouldn't be like that, here what I tried:

**html:**

```
      <label for="place">Einheit</label>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [disabled]="!selectedplace" type="button">Change</button>
        </div>
        <select id="place" name="place" #place="ngModel" required class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="selectedplace" (change)="onDropdownChangeplace()">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option *ngFor="let i of UI_places" [ngValue]="i">{{i.name}}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="place.touched && !place.valid">Bitte eine Eingeben eingeben!</div>
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [disabled]="!selectedplace" type="button">Add</button>
          <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [disabled]="!selectedplace" type="button">Delete(red)</button>
        </div>
      </div>
```

TypeScript(declared):

```
public selectedplace: Place;
```

What should I do ?

Comment: You mean you want it disabled when you select this option `<option value=""></option>`?

Comment: *when I change the option*: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Provide ts code which handle the buttons, otherwise it is guessing what is right or wrong, but I assume, you don't reset the `selectedplace` property once it is initiated.

Comment: Yes @igor_c, you are right. Sorry for the the confusion.

Comment: Check the stack blitz and maybe edit to provide a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing in `onDropdownChangeplace`. My guess is that you assign a value based on the index changed.

When you don't assign the value (in case of empty selection), then the previous value remains binded to ngModel.

Check [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-so-formarray-example-vzff2e). Based on your code, it is enabling and disabling pretty well.

That's the code in the component. I left the html exactly as you sent it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent {
    public UI_places = [{id:0, name: 'home'},{id:1, name: 'work'}];
    public selectedplace: Place;

    onDropdownChangeplace() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Htank you, "When you don't assign the value (in case of empty selection), then the previous value remains binded to ngModel", you are right :)